# Handling Cloudflare captcha on Login form in Cypress Automated Test?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, cloudflare, captcha

We recently added this Cloudflare verification to the login form. We login via API for 99% of our tests but still want a few tests that use the actual login form so we know if it's broken. I updated the test to click the captcha but it just get stuck in a loop. Has anyone dealt with this before?

[image: captcha]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it can be answered without giving a full-blown tutorial, but these references might be useful.

[Turnstile Overview](https://developers.cloudflare.com/turnstile/)

[image: Turnstile Overview diagram]

[Testing](https://developers.cloudflare.com/turnstile/reference/testing/)

**Dummy sitekeys and secret keys**
The following sitekeys and secret keys are available for testing.

| Sitekey | Description | Visibility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1x00000000000000000000AA | Always passes | visible |
| 2x00000000000000000000AB | Always blocks | visible |
| 1x00000000000000000000BB | Always passes | invisible |
| 2x00000000000000000000BB | Always blocks | invisible |
| 3x00000000000000000000FF | Forces an interactive challenge | visible |

| Secret key | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1x0000000000000000000000000000000AA | Always passes |
| 2x0000000000000000000000000000000AA | Always fails |
| 3x0000000000000000000000000000000AA | Yields a “token already spent” error |